# Typescript Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'HTMLElement'

Tags: typescript

I have the following code using Typescript 3.5.1

```js
class MyParent<T extends HTMLElement> {
    eFoo: T;
}

class MyChild<T = HTMLInputElement> extends MyParent<T> {
    foo() {
        this.eFoo.value = 'bar';
    }
}

class GrandChild extends MyChild<HTMLTextAreaElement> {
    foo() {
        this.eFoo.value = 'baz';
    }
}
```

The second class `MyChild` has a compilation error that I don't quite understand

1. "Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'HTMLElement'."
2. "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'T'."

The `GrandChild` class seems fine, no errors at all.

Comment: No, `HTMLTextAreaElement`  is extended from `HTMLElement`, same as `HTMLInputElement`.

Comment: Yeah, I quite missed the meaning of `=`. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyChild<T = HTMLInputElement> extends MyParent<T> {
    foo() {
        this.eFoo.value = 'bar';
    }
}
```

The `T = HTMLInputElement` means that T has a default value of HTMLInputElement, but T could be *any type*: You haven't [constrained T](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) for MyChild. It could be `SomeOtherClass`, or `{}`, or `number`, or `never`. Therefore, it is not an appropriate substitute for the `T extends HTMLElement` in `MyParent<T>` (your first error message), and contains no properties like `value` for sure (your second error message).

You can constrain it as you did MyParent, in syntax [described in Typescript 2.3's release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults):

```
class MyChild<T extends HTMLInputElement = HTMLInputElement> extends MyParent<T> {
    foo() {
        this.eFoo.value = 'bar';
    }
}
```

Now for all T values, `myChild.eFoo` is sure to have a `value`.

---

As a side note to your example code, please be aware that HTMLTextAreaElement does not extend HTMLInputElement. If you want `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements to apply to MyChild, you may need to change your type parameters and expectations.

Comment: Great, I didn't know I had to specify extends again since MyChild extends MyParent.

Comment: @GuilhermeLopez: Glad to help! Remember, MyChild's T is an entirely separate type variable, and TypeScript doesn't know how you intend to use it: Maybe it's okay for T to be a number, because `MyChild<number>` just makes that number appear in eFoo's HTMLElement somewhere. Good luck!